# Object required (Error 424) in Select Case

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have the following code in VBA editor Sheet2:

```
Sub Organize_Data()
Dim i As Integer
Dim S2 As Worksheet, S3 As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set S2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set S3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

S3.Range("A:G").Clear
S2.Range("F:H").Copy Destination:=S3.Range("A:C")
S2.Range("P:P").Copy Destination:=S3.Range("F:F")
S2.Range("K:K").Copy Destination:=S3.Range("G:G")


S3.Columns("A:G").Sort key1:=S3.Range("A2"), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

S3.Cells(1, 4) = "Name Boy"
S3.Cells(1, 5) = "Name Girl"
Last = S3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 2 Step -1
If Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 16 Or Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 18 Then
Boys_Girls1
ElseIf Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 23 Then
Boys_Girls2
Else
S3.Cells(i, "D") = ""
S3.Cells(i, "E") = ""
End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub Boys_Girls1()
BOY = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 6, 2)
Select Case BOY
    Case Is = "AM", "01"
        S3.Cells(i, "D") = "Aaron Mitchels"
    Case Is = "BP"
        S3.Cells(i, "D") = "Brian Parker"
    Case Else
        S3.Cells(i, "D") = ""
End Select
GIRL = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 8, 2)
Select Case GIRL
    Case Is = "AL"
        S3.Cells(i, "E") = "Alexa"
    Case Is = "EQ", "02"
        S3.Cells(i, "E") = "Elizabeth Queen"
    Case Else
        S3.Cells(i, "E") = ""
End Select
End Sub

Sub Boys_Girls2()
BOY = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 10, 2)
Select Case BOY
    Case Is = "AM", "01"
        S3.Cells(i, "D") = "Aaron Mitchels"
    Case Is = "BP"
        S3.Cells(i, "D") = "Brian Parker"
    Case Else
        S3.Cells(i, "D") = ""
End Select
GIRL = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 12, 2)
Select Case GIRL
    Case Is = "AL"
        S3.Cells(i, "E") = "Alexa"
    Case Is = "EQ", "02"
        S3.Cells(i, "E") = "Elizabeth Queen"
    Case Else
        S3.Cells(i, "E") = ""
End Select
End Sub
```

The purpose of the program is to copy a data set from Sheet2 and paste it to Sheet3, then to organize the format like performing ascending order and labeling data. When I ran the program, **the run-time error '424': Object required** kept popping up. The error doesn't point to any lines but the code perfectly works when it doesn't call the procedures. I was not able to find a way to figure it out for hours nor also to find an idea from online search. Could someone here explain what is wrong in my program and how to fix it?

Comment: Where does the error point to?

Comment: @RGA Please see my edit. I added: "The error doesn't point to any lines but the code perfectly works when it doesn't call the procedures".

Comment: Your `S3` variable is declared in the first sub so is not visible to the second or third routines. You should either declare it at module level or pass it to the other routines as an argument.

Comment: All I can see is that the `Boys_Girls1` and `Boys_Girls2` procedures have no idea what `i` means as it's declared only in `Organize_Data`.

Comment: @Rory I did declare `S2` and `S3` as global variables or put them also in the procedures but the error kept showed up.

Comment: try to add break points, to debug your code

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier Like what? Sorry, I didn't understand. I'm new in VBA Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code (and assuming you have included everything), it seems you never defined the `BOY` and `GIRL` variables in the last to Subroutines.  Add the line `Dim BOY As String, Girl As String` to both Subs and it should eliminate that error.

As pointed out by another commenter, the S3 variable is also not available to the subsequent subroutines, given the variable scope.  You can either pass it as a parameter of the subroutines or make the variable global. Either solution would work

In general, you seem to be having an issue with variable Scope. This [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693) can help you understand the nuances in VBA.  In terms of this particular issue, are you sure it is necessary to even be calling a seperate routine?  Given the short length of the routines and since it seems they are only called in one condition, you could solve most of your problems simultaneously by simply moving those processes inside the original routine

In response to OP's comment, I have included the fixed parts of code below:

```
If Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 16 Or Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 18 Then
Boys_Girls1(S3,i)
ElseIf Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 23 Then
Boys_Girls2(S3,i)



Sub Boys_Girls1(InputSheet As WorkSheet, InputRow As Long)
'Your code here (replace calls to S3 with InputSheet and calls to i with InputRow)
End Sub

Sub Boys_Girls2(InputSheet As WorkSheet, InputRow As Long)
'Your code here (replace calls to S3 with InputSheet and calls to i with InputRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you fix the code by adding your answer to it? I'm confused. About calling the subroutines I refer to [this site](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson05.htm), it says it doesn't matter if you don't put `Call`

Comment: I agree with Anastasiya - you can call the routines using just the name, no need for the `Call` keyword.  But - you're not declaring `i` so it's a variant which means on the first line of your code `BOY = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 6, 2)` - `i` is `empty` which will cause the error you're getting.

Comment: While it is true that they can be called without the `Call` keyword, its good practice to always include it so you can see where you are referencing a subroutine more easily.  I personally prefer to always use the `Application.Run` method as this will prevent errors that arrise if a subroutine is changed to be private or if the code is moved to a different Module.  Technically not requirements for running code, but good ways to save yourself from future headache (hence why i included it among the other solutions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. Thanks also for the advice. It seemed I finally found the error. (+1)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 If my solution (or another) turned out to be the correct answer for your question, please mark it as accepted to remove this question from the unanswered question queue

Comment: Call is not "good practice", it's a personal preference only. Run breaks the call stack so is not, IMO, good practice.

Comment: @Rory if a subroutine is private, can it be called without using application.run?  I will remove the paragraph about the Call statement, as it is clear to me now that that is not a valid solution, but I am now curious as to exactly what the VBA rules are for calling subroutines

Comment: It depends where the calling code is. But the fact that Run violates scope is not really a good reason to use it! :)

Comment: @Rory can you explain what you mean by "violates scope"?  I know that run is needed to call a private subroutine in a different module, is this what you are referring to?  (Self-taught VBA user so I like learning these sorts of technicallities rather than always repeating unnecessary keywords because someone somewhere said so!)

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. If a routine is private you should not be able to call it from elsewhere - that's the point of it being private. Run shouldn't be allowed to ignore that!!

Comment: @Rory I've used private in the past in order to prevent users from accessing the macro from the macros menu.  Is there a better way to do this without forcing me to use run and violate scope?

Comment: Either use Option Private Module or add an optional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your routines as below.  Note I'm passing the `S3` and `i` variables to the two routines and `Option Explicit` should be at the very top of the module before any procedures.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Organize_Data()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim S2 As Worksheet, S3 As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set S2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set S3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    S3.Range("A:G").Clear
    S2.Range("F:H").Copy Destination:=S3.Range("A:C")
    S2.Range("P:P").Copy Destination:=S3.Range("F:F")
    S2.Range("K:K").Copy Destination:=S3.Range("G:G")

    S3.Columns("A:G").Sort key1:=S3.Range("A2"), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    S3.Cells(1, 4) = "Name Boy"
    S3.Cells(1, 5) = "Name Girl"
    Last = S3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 16 Or Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 18 Then
            Boys_Girls1 S3, i
        ElseIf Len(S3.Cells(i, "A")) = 23 Then
            Boys_Girls2 S3, i
        Else
            S3.Cells(i, "D") = ""
            S3.Cells(i, "E") = ""
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub Boys_Girls1(S3 As Worksheet, i As Integer)

    Dim BOY As String, GIRL As String

    BOY = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 6, 2)
    Select Case BOY
        Case Is = "AM", "01"
            S3.Cells(i, "D") = "Aaron Mitchels"
        Case Is = "BP"
            S3.Cells(i, "D") = "Brian Parker"
        Case Else
            S3.Cells(i, "D") = ""
    End Select
    GIRL = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 8, 2)
    Select Case GIRL
        Case Is = "AL"
            S3.Cells(i, "E") = "Alexa"
        Case Is = "EQ", "02"
            S3.Cells(i, "E") = "Elizabeth Queen"
        Case Else
            S3.Cells(i, "E") = ""
    End Select

End Sub

Sub Boys_Girls2(Sht As Worksheet, i As Integer)

    Dim BOY As String, GIRL As String

    BOY = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 10, 2)
    Select Case BOY
        Case Is = "AM", "01"
            S3.Cells(i, "D") = "Aaron Mitchels"
        Case Is = "BP"
            S3.Cells(i, "D") = "Brian Parker"
        Case Else
            S3.Cells(i, "D") = ""
    End Select
    GIRL = Mid(S3.Cells(i, "A"), 12, 2)
    Select Case GIRL
        Case Is = "AL"
            S3.Cells(i, "E") = "Alexa"
        Case Is = "EQ", "02"
            S3.Cells(i, "E") = "Elizabeth Queen"
        Case Else
            S3.Cells(i, "E") = ""
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Why should I put `Option Explicit` at the top? Anyway, when I declare both `i` and `S3` as global variables the code perfectly works. Is that a problem with the way I handle the error? (+1) anyway

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 Option Explicit is a VBA coder's best friend, as it helps you avoid variable name issues (particularly given that VBA variables are case-sensitive), which helps avoid errors from miscelaneous typos

Comment: As RGA said - except the case-sensitive bit.  You can declare `i` and `s3` as global - that'll work to, but I prefer to keep the scope of variables to the minimum required.